# Por qué me sale este error? Compilation error: expected primary-expression before '!=' token

Tags: arduino

He tenido que hacer un trabajo para mi colegio y me ha salido este error, como no se mucho del tema he visto un tutorial y bueno he mejorado un poco el código pero aun aún asi me sale error, el código es para controlar un brazo robótico
Este código no es mio lo descargue pero lo edite un poco ya que me marcaba bastantes errores, no puedo avanzar asi, me marca error en las líneas 36 y 52 del código

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo hombro, codo, muneca, pinzas, base;
int phombro, pcodo, pmuneca, ppinzas ,pbase, contador=0;
int fact;
 void setup(){
  hombro.attach(13);
  codo.attach(12);
  muneca.attach(11);
  pinzas.attach(10);
  base.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
 }
void loop()
{
  if(contador==0)
  {
    phombro=hombro.read();
    pcodo=codo.read();
    pmuneca=muneca.read();
    ppinzas=pinzas.read();
    pbase=base.read();

   hombro.write(phombro);
    codo.write(pcodo);
    muneca.write(pmuneca);
    pinzas.write(ppinzas);
    base.write(pbase);
    contador++;    
  }
  fact='x';
  fact=Serial.read();
  switch(fact)
  {
    case 'a':
    {
      while(Serial.read())!='x';
      {
        if(phombro>=175)
        phombro=175;
        if(phombro<=180 && phombro>=0)
         {
          phombro++;
          hombro.write(phombro);
          delay(15);
         }
      }
    }
    break;

    case 'b':
    {
      while(Serial.read())!='x';
      {
        if(phombro<=5)
        phombro=5;
        if(phombro<=180 && phombro>=0)
        {
          phombro--;
          hombro.write(phombro);
          delay(15);
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Debe ser `while(Serial.read() != 'x');` Tienes un cierra paréntesis mal colocado. Claro que es mala idea hacer ciclos dentro de `loop()`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes

```
case 'a':
{
  while(Serial.read())!='x';
  {
```

donde parece que la intención es no hacer nada hasta que la puerta serial retorne un 'x'.

La expresión está mal construida; el cierra paréntesis está mal puesto. La forma correcta es

```
case 'a':
{
  while (Serial.read() != 'x') ;
  {
```

Answer (score 0):

El parentesis esta mal puesto en la linea 36

```
//Correcto
while( Serial.read() != 'x');
```